# Imported data from CSV doesnt seem to be able to plot in PYTHON

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I can't seem to plot a graph using the below code. I wish to plot a graph with the total returns against the Date. What is wrong with my code?

I get KeyError: ' Date'

Spreadsheet is presented below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader import data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# import data from csv into a dataframe

sp500 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\James\SPX.csv', index_col = 'Date')

print sp500.tail()

#test plot to see if it works

x = sp500['Date']
y = sp500['Total Return']


plt.plot(x,y)
```

Data is in the format below:

```
           Cash Close Total Return Futures Open Futures Close Futures High  \
Date
23-Dec-16   2,263.79     3,052.05     2,257.50      2,260.00     2,261.00
27-Dec-16   2,268.88     3,058.94     2,258.75      2,261.00     2,269.50
28-Dec-16   2,249.92     3,033.90     2,261.25      2,245.25     2,267.50
29-Dec-16   2,249.26     3,033.16     2,245.50      2,245.00     2,250.00
30-Dec-16   2,238.83     3,019.24     2,246.25      2,236.25     2,252.75
```

Data is presented below

```
Date,Cash Close,Total Return,Futures Open,Futures Close,Futures High,Futures Low,Risk Free Rate
2-Jan-01," 1,283.27 "," 1,283.27 "," 1,331.00 "," 1,299.80 "," 1,336.75 "," 1,289.25 ",6.50%
3-Jan-01," 1,347.56 "," 1,347.56 "," 1,301.00 "," 1,359.20 "," 1,367.25 "," 1,288.75 ",6.00%
4-Jan-01," 1,333.34 "," 1,333.34 "," 1,360.00 "," 1,348.30 "," 1,365.50 "," 1,341.50 ",6.00%
5-Jan-01," 1,298.35 "," 1,298.35 "," 1,345.75 "," 1,304.50 "," 1,380.00 "," 1,303.00 ",6.00%
8-Jan-01," 1,295.86 "," 1,295.86 "," 1,308.25 "," 1,309.50 "," 1,312.50 "," 1,287.50 ",6.00%
9-Jan-01," 1,300.80 "," 1,300.80 "," 1,312.00 "," 1,309.50 "," 1,325.50 "," 1,303.75 ",6.00%
10-Jan-01," 1,313.27 "," 1,313.27 "," 1,309.50 "," 1,327.00 "," 1,328.75 "," 1,297.25 ",6.00%
11-Jan-01," 1,326.82 "," 1,326.82 "," 1,325.75 "," 1,334.50 "," 1,343.50 "," 1,319.50 ",6.00%
12-Jan-01," 1,318.32 "," 1,318.32 "," 1,332.00 "," 1,330.30 "," 1,344.75 "," 1,322.00 ",6.00%
16-Jan-01," 1,326.65 "," 1,326.65 "," 1,328.75 "," 1,335.50 "," 1,339.50 "," 1,323.50 ",6.00%
17-Jan-01," 1,329.47 "," 1,329.47 "," 1,337.25 "," 1,341.70 "," 1,357.75 "," 1,334.50 ",6.00%
18-Jan-01," 1,347.97 "," 1,347.97 "," 1,342.50 "," 1,356.00 "," 1,364.00 "," 1,337.00 ",6.00%
19-Jan-01," 1,342.54 "," 1,342.54 "," 1,359.00 "," 1,348.50 "," 1,371.75 "," 1,345.75 ",6.00%
22-Jan-01," 1,342.90 "," 1,342.90 "," 1,346.00 "," 1,358.50 "," 1,364.00 "," 1,341.25 ",6.00%
23-Jan-01," 1,360.40 "," 1,360.40 "," 1,356.75 "," 1,366.00 "," 1,372.75 "," 1,348.50 ",6.00%
24-Jan-01," 1,364.30 "," 1,364.30 "," 1,366.25 "," 1,370.20 "," 1,379.00 "," 1,365.25 ",6.00%
25-Jan-01," 1,357.51 "," 1,357.51 "," 1,369.75 "," 1,364.50 "," 1,378.75 "," 1,362.75 ",6.00%
26-Jan-01," 1,354.95 "," 1,354.95 "," 1,364.25 "," 1,363.30 "," 1,366.75 "," 1,350.25 ",6.00%
29-Jan-01," 1,364.17 "," 1,364.17 "," 1,363.00 "," 1,370.00 "," 1,374.00 "," 1,358.50 ",6.00%
30-Jan-01," 1,373.73 "," 1,373.73 "," 1,370.25 "," 1,382.00 "," 1,384.25 "," 1,363.25 ",6.00%
31-Jan-01," 1,366.01 "," 1,366.01 "," 1,381.00 "," 1,372.90 "," 1,394.00 "," 1,371.25 ",5.50%
1-Feb-01," 1,373.47 "," 1,373.47 "," 1,397.90 "," 1,397.90 "," 1,397.90 "," 1,397.90 ",5.50%
2-Feb-01," 1,349.47 "," 1,349.47 "," 1,368.30 "," 1,368.30 "," 1,368.30 "," 1,368.30 ",5.50%
```

Comment: Not sure what your question/issue is. Also: in the future, pay attention to code formatting. As originally posted, it was unreadable (I formatted it).

Comment: Thanks buddy, let me re-edit the question too. Cheers.

Comment: Are you running jupyter notebook or jupyter QT console ?

Comment: I am using simple python 2.7+ and CMD to run the code. 
Also Notepad++. Completely new to python, sorry for noob questions

Comment: Did you call `plt.show() `?

Comment: I did, but it says KeyError : ' Date'

Comment: Your data isn't actually in CSV (Comma Separated Value) format, as you specify in the question. If you put it in CSV format, this may help you.

Comment: @CDahn - Quite sure data is in CSV format. It starts with a header, followed by the data. I saved it from excel into CSV, before importing.

Comment: @ksai  this doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @james, not to be contrarian, but looking at your "Data is in the format below" section above, there is a distinct lack of commas separating the data. Therefore it is most definitely, from what I can tell, not in CSV format.

Comment: @CDahn thanks for the prompt reply, but i am very confused now. the data was from the sp500.tail() 
sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @james, got that. All I'm saying is that lacking actual data that you're ingesting into your code, helping you becomes a bit like interpreting tea leaves. My only hypothesis is that your data isn't split up the way you think it is, but that's impossible to prove because you haven't given us the data you're ingesting. Rather, you've provided a pretty-printed rendition of it. One thing that leads me to this hypothesis is that your data contains commas, or so it appears. Parsing errors could be dooming you here.

Comment: I think you get `KeyError` in `x = sp500['Date']` ,

Comment: yes, how do I solve that? :(

Comment: you need to `reset_index()` or remove `index_col` from `pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\James\SPX.csv', index_col = 'Date')`

Comment: @CDahn I have uploaded my ".CSV" file if you can kindly help me to check please?

Comment: @ksai i tried removing index_col = ' Date', i got an AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'find'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have here starts at the point where you create your csv file. One line of the file looks like this

```
2-Jan-01," 1,283.27 "," 1,283.27 "," 1,331.00 "," 1,299.80 "," 1,336.75 "," 1,289.25 ",6.50%
```

As you can see, you are using commas (`,`) as field separators as well as as thousands separators. This makes it necessary that the field values are encapsulated into quote signs (`"`). In turn this leads to pandas needing to read the fields as strings and not as numbers.

An option is of course changing the csv format of the file at creation. If this is not possible, you would need to use some of the options that [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) offers to correctly read in the data.

```
sp500 = pd.read_csv('spx1.csv', index_col = 'Date', 
                    parse_dates=True, thousands=r",", quotechar='"')
```

Now comes the second problem: You don't have a "Date" column. "Date" is the index of the dataframe, not a column (because you use `index_col = 'Date'`). You would therefore need to use this index as the values for `x` to be plotted,

```
x = sp500.index
```

A complete example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# import data from csv into a dataframe
sp500 = pd.read_csv('spx1.csv', index_col = 'Date', parse_dates=True, 
                    thousands=r",", quotechar='"')

x = sp500.index
y = sp500['Total Return']

plt.plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, you have no idea how helpful this is to me and my slow understanding of python/pandas.

Cheers to your great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('spx1.csv', index_col = 'Date')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index) #convert index to datetime
x = list(df.index.values) # get index list
y = [float(e.strip().replace(',','')) for e in df['Total Return'].tolist()] #convert to float and get as list
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

it will show:

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @james cheers :) if it is helpful, don't forget to mark it as accept answer :)

Comment: Sure. If you dont mind helping, could you explain why i have to manipulate the data as such, conversion into a float and then a list before i can plot?

Comment: as df columns are strings with ',', when plot, plot cannot convert these string to float, you need to remove ',' first, then convert to float, after that plot can work. and refer to https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html for more infor.